# Static Publishing in Silverstripe on Large Sites

Tags: silverstripe

My company uses SilverStripe v3.1.21, along with the Subsite module to display and administer a number of clients' websites that sell products. This results in close to 200 subsites and a page count in the tens of thousands. The websites are very slow to load and tools such as Google's PageSpeed tell us page speeds are poor. We've already done step like combining and minimising the JS and compressing resources such as imaging, which gave some improvements, however the pages remain slow. The system was handed to us in this state and further hardware upgrades are not on the table as an option, nor are gaining additional resources for redevelopment.

We've taken a look at the static publish module (https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-staticpublisher) and found that when we generating static pages the pages become fast and get a good score on the various tools, however the process to regenerate all of these pages takes over 14 hours, which is unacceptable given these products are updated from an external source daily. We also find that the regeneration process is a memory hog, as the module builds all of the pages in memory before dumping to file, causing the process to crash. We've had to alter the process to go subsite-by-subsite just to make it run.

We then took a look at the static publishing queue module (https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-staticpublishqueue), which seemed to address our issues by having it queue pages as needed for regeneration, making it much more responsive to changes. However, the module seems to be very buggy and often crashes when generating pages.

Has anyone had experience using these modules (or similar) with larger sites and may be able to provide any pointers or ideas on how to implement static publishing successfully?

Comment: adding partial caching might also speed up static publisher, as it doesn't have to calulcate everything all the time. See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/performance/partial_caching/

Comment: Partial caching might or might not help, mostly depending on what is the bottleneck. We've had trouble with navigation generation performance mostly. Partial cache doesn't help a lot if the navigation needs `active` / `path` etc. classes in HTML as it needs to be regenerated for every single page.

Comment: @koodimyyra of course, but you can e.g. cache an inactive subtree, so it might help a little bit

Comment: @wmk true, if you need to display inactive subtrees at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using staticpublishqueue currently on several sites.  The only problem we've had with it is crashing due to long builds and poor locking.  Or to be precise it doesn't actually crash but keeps spawning more and more instances until the server becomes unresponsible.

I think we have a fix for this in our [fork](https://github.com/Focus-Flow/silverstripe-staticpublishqueue/).  At least we haven't had any problems after using the modified locking.  You could try installing [the fork](https://github.com/Focus-Flow/silverstripe-staticpublishqueue/) instead of the official version.  If this fixes things for you maybe we should make a pull request :)

Comment: Thanks, it makes it much more stable for us. We've forked again as we have a number of DataObject subclasses that get generated as pages, which aren't under SiteTree, so needed a way to make them publishable as well.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works for you too! Will work on creating a pull request soon.

Comment: Finally got around making the pull request, see https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-staticpublishqueue/pull/68.

Answer (score 1):

First of: We only use staticpublishqueue, I don't have any experience in regards to the sub site module. So I can't speak for your exact combination.

We are using staticpublishqueue on a huge site. Setup: We have multiple servers running the SilverStripe Website. They share a MySQL Database and use Redis as a session store. 
One great thing about staticpublishqueue: you can run it in parallel. So the servers all run an instance of staticpublishqueue and publish into a shared folder, which is then synced to a nginx load balancer in front of the actual webservers. Works quite nice, but it does not scale indefinitely. At some point the staticpublishqueue instances start to pick the same record to render and waste resources. I think about 6 is the max for us.

Couple of things we learned regarding staticpublishqueue:

- do not run to many instances at the same time (see above)
- make sure it has enough ram
- make sure it runs as the same user as the website
- the record look it uses is not compatible with a MariaDB Galera Cluster
- If possible switch to SilverStripe 3.6.x and PHP7. The performance gain is huge.

We are migrating away from staticpublishqueue to Cloudflare (or maybe another CDN). Why? Because if a page that is requested has not been rendered yet the server will render it for each request individually and then throw it away. Until the que does a separate render for the cache. Total waste of resources, especially if you purge your cache after a sitewide layout change or something.