# Static Publishing and HTTPS

Tags: silverstripe

Following this question : [Static Publishing in Silverstripe on Large Sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313840/static-publishing-in-silverstripe-on-large-sites)

We've been implementing the module from this fork (https://github.com/Focus-Flow/silverstripe-staticpublishqueue/) and it's working great locally. We have done some modification to implement our own categories page, but nothing special.

The only issue is now when we test on our server, which use https rather than http in local, nothing is working anymore. I've been trying to change a couple of thing in the FileSystemPublisher.php file to use https rather than http, but it's not doing anything.

An other thing, and it might be linked, when I go in the admin backend of our subsites, all the page links in the edit page are in "http" and apparently there is a https redirection on the server.

So I guess I have two questions :

- How to make static publishing queue work with https ?
- How to make silverstripe understand that all of the website page should be in https and not in http, so it shows this way in the admin backend ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I came across the same issue. The only way we could solve the issue is to add the following line to our `_config.php` file:  `Director::setBaseURL('https://www.example.com/');`

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing that too, but it can't work with subsites right ?

Comment: Good point. I have not tried static publisher with the subsites module.

Comment: It actually might work with your idea, but the issue I have now is that the page is properly cached, but it still link to css and js with http, so it's not valid, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subsite` has a method called `absoluteBaseURL()`, so you might try this in your `Page_Controller::init()`:

```
$currentSubsite = Subsite::currentSubsite();

Director::setBaseURL($currentSubsite->absoluteBaseURL());
```

Of course you need to configure Subsite's Domains including https

Comment: thanks, it worked. Now I have a new problem, but the https one is resolved :)

Comment: for reference, it needs to be : 
$currentSubsite = Subsite::currentSubsite();
if ($currentSubsite)
Director::setBaseURL($currentSubsite->absoluteBaseURL());

Otherwise you will have an error 500 or the admin panel.