# Redirect issue static publishing and subsite

Tags: silverstripe

Following this question : [Static Publishing and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445960/static-publishing-and-https)

I got static publishing to work with https now, but I have a new issue still linked to subsite.

Everything seems to work with the cache, but when I change the primary domain of a subsite, I have a redirection message whenever I try to cache something using

```
framework/sake dev/tasks/BuildStaticCacheFromQueue daemon=1 verbose=1
```

Redirect message :

```
FilesystemPublisher: Publishing to https://xxx.yy/
 * Publishing page 1/1: https://xxx.yy/a/b/?_ID=10923&_ClassName=CategoryTreePage
Url : https://xxx.yy/a/b/
<p>Redirecting to <a href="https://xxx.yy/a/b/" title="Click this link if your browser does not redirect you">https://xxx.yy/a/b/... (output started on SSImageCacheTask.php, line 80)</a></p>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=https://xxx.yy/a/b/" />
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "https://xxx.yy/a/b/";
```

SsImageCacheTask.php being a random module that isn't responsible as I've done tests removing it, and it's the same message.

As a final note, the websites are working fine, the only issue is the caching.

Am I supposed to flush something that I haven't or run a script through the DB or something ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: there is a file called `host-map.php` in your subsites module folder which is used by static publisher. Does this reflect your changes on the domain? You might also wipe out the static cache files on your server. (on an older 3.1 installation with Subsites and Static Publisher I have a file called _homepage-map.php in assets for this)

Comment: Are you talking about a cached file concerning subsites ? Where is it located exactly ? Otherwise, the host-map file looks good, it's written "// Generated by Subsite::writeHostMap() on 24/Nov/17" at the top, date of the last modif

Comment: Does that queue a "halt" on the queue? If the databases queue table contains  that,the redirector, and the target page and they get their html files generated is there actually an issue?

Comment: First it doesn't clean the queue, so the page is always waiting to be cached.
And also I can go on the page that is being cached without being redirected, so there is no reason to get this message.